# Can a French plan épargne logement (PEL) have an IBAN number?

Tags: france, iban

I wonder the following: can a French [plan épargne logement (PEL)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_%C3%A9pargne_logement) account have an IBAN number?

Comment: It probably can, but that does not necessarily mean you can use it. Lots of types of accounts do not accept incoming or outgoing transfers from/to anything else than the account holder’s other accounts at the same bank.

Comment: @jcaron Good point! Follow-up: [Do French plan épargne logement (PEL) accounts accept incoming transfers from bank accounts that are not the account holder’s other accounts at the same bank?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/158049/5656)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to these [posts](https://redd.it/15v26v9), a French plan épargne logement (PEL) has an IBAN number but that doesn't mean it can receive any transfer.