# Do French plan épargne logement accounts accept incoming transfers from bank accounts that aren't the account holder’s other accounts at the same bank

Tags: money-transfer, france

Do French [plan épargne logement (PEL)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_%C3%A9pargne_logement) accounts accept incoming transfers from bank accounts that are not the account holder’s other accounts at the same bank?

Comment: Sorry, too lazy to write an answer: https://www.inc-conso.fr/content/quelles-operations-puis-je-faire-sur-mon-livret-ou-compte-depargne though some things in there seem contradictory (no IBAN but you would supposedly be able to make a transfer from your current account to a _livret_ in your name held in a different bank? Not sure I understand how you would do that)

Comment: @jcaron Thanks, I'm also confused: https://www.reddit.com/r/vosfinances/comments/51esut/ibanrib_du_pel_pour_transfert/dcssrhf/ says one can infer the IBAN.  https://www.moneyvox.fr/forums/fil/rib-iban-dun-compte-epargne.12744/ says it's not possible to wire to PEL, etc. No idea why the question got downvoted, probably someone who has clues what PEL is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jcaron](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/35356/jcaron) shared the https://www.inc-conso.fr/content/quelles-operations-puis-je-faire-sur-mon-livret-ou-compte-depargne, which answers the question:

> 3 - Quelles sont les opérations autorisées sur les livrets et les comptes d'épargne ?
>
> Les opérations qui, en principe, sont autorisées :
>
> - **les virements ponctuels de votre compte courant vers un compte épargne** **à votre nom**, même détenu dans une autre banque,
> - **les virements ponctuels de votre compte épargne vers un compte courant à votre nom**, même détenu dans une autre banque,
> - **les virements permanents de votre compte courant vers un compte épargne à votre nom** dans la même banque.

Translation via Gtranslate:

> 3 - What operations are authorized on livrets and savings accounts?
>
> Operations which, in principle, are authorized:
>
> - **one-off transfers from your current account to a savings account** **in your name**, even held in another bank,
> - **one-off transfers from your savings account to a current account in your name**, even held in another bank,
> - **permanent transfers from your current account to a savings account in your name** at the same bank.